# Export generic code (List<T>)to COM

Tags: c#, list, generics, com

COM doesn't support generics?What would be the best way to replicate this `List<T>` so that it's COM visible in the tlh file.
EDIT::
 c#::

```
[ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("FA677671-5E26-4307-AD2B-19BF1E7AFF8B")]
    public interface IEvents
    {
        IEvents[] CreateListeners();
    }
```

in C++ i have,

```
CComSafeArray<CSharp::IEvents> ppSA;
    pInterface->CreateListeners(ppSA->GetSafeArrayPtr());
```

My question what i should do in this Create instance function so asto replicate this statement 
List evt=new List();
in the managed c#?

Comment: You've shown us *no* code - what do you expect us to suggest?

Comment: Where do you want to Export the List?

Comment: There are allot of question on this issue:

[C# exposing class to COM - Generic Collections][1]

[What are alternatives to generic collections for COM Interop?][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862497/c-sharp-exposing-class-to-com-generic-collections
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269581/what-are-alternatives-to-generic-collections-for-com-interop

Comment: @Beno, take a look at my update.Want an insight into the SAFEARRAY thingy

Answer (score 2):

Correct, generic types are not supported:

> The COM model does not support the concept of generic types. Consequently, generic types cannot be used directly for COM interop.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229590.aspx

Perhaps this is the place to start:

[C# exposing class to COM - Generic Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862497/c-sharp-exposing-class-to-com-generic-collections)

Comment: This is precisely what I did! but wanted to know if any other shortcut? cause I am finding difficult in using SAFARRAY(add items,modify items) that gets formed in tlh file.

Comment: How to create a SAFEARRAY of objects. I saw the example of SAFEARRAY of primitive datatypes?Any links?