# Howto author a scriptable collection in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, collections, vbscript, com-interop

I need to author a .NET assembly that is visible as a COM object through COM Interop, such that it can supply a collection to a VBScript or JScript program.

When I use simple collections such as ArrayList, that flows through COM interop and can be iterated over in VBScript using a program like this:

```
Dim s, foo
Set foo = CreateObject("Whatever.Collection")
For Each s In foo
    WScript.Echo s
Next
```

Now, if instead of ArrayList I use somethign based on a generic collection class, such as `List<string>`, or `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`, that doesn't seem to work in the VBScript. I get errors in the For Each loop, like

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required:

So, it seems like there is some magic sauce that I'm missing here somewhere. What does it take to make a .NET collection flow through COM Interop and work correctly in VBScript and JScript?

Comment: As far as I know generics aren't supported in interop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started looking to see if there is a solution to this since I didn't think it was possible. It seems like Rick Strahl has a [solution](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/111617.aspx).

**Edit**: Here is another solution on SO [What are alternatives to generic collections for COM Interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269581/what-are-alternatives-to-generic-collections-for-com-interop)